# Vscode virtual envir setting cmd sucess vscode fail

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Through cmd:
[image]

you see, the virtual_env can function well; however, when I use Vscode:
[image]

they are the same dir; so no idea why its failed...some others may also have this problem, so I post it here

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Python extension for VS Code it will do the activation for you automatically. But the problem you're specifically having is you are running PowerShell as your shell, not Command Prompt. You can use the `Terminal: Select Default Shell` command to change to Command Prompt or you need to change how you affect your virtual environment for PowerShell: `./activate` if you're in your `Scripts/` directory.